# AutoPostBackOnFilter failing

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have auto generated columns in my radgrid and i'm trying to enable column filtering on enter key press. when i type search text and press enter i'm getting the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gridSearchL3" runat="server" AllowPagg="True" 
             GridLines="None" Height="415px" 
             OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
            Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="Small" PageSize="50" 
             AllowFilteringByColumn="True"

             AllowSorting="True" ShowStatusBar="True" AllowPaging="True" CellSpacing="0" 
                oncolumncreated="gridSearchL3_ColumnCreated1" onitemcommand="gridSearchL3_ItemCommand" 
                >
               <FilterItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="XX-Small" />
               <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="False" />
            <ExportSettings Excel-Format="ExcelML" ExportOnlyData="True" 
                FileName="PinC Group" IgnorePaging="True" OpenInNewWindow="True">
                <Excel Format="ExcelML" />
            </ExportSettings>
            <ClientSettings>

                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />

            </ClientSettings>
            <AlternatingItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
            <GroupHeaderItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
            <SortingSettings EnableSkinSortStyles="false" /> 
            <MasterTableView  Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" 
                   Font-Size="X-Small">

                <CommandItemSettings  ExportToPdfText="Export to Pdf" />

                <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
                </RowIndicatorColumn>
                <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
                </ExpandCollapseColumn>

                <EditFormSettings>
                    <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                    </EditColumn>
                </EditFormSettings>
                <ItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
                <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" />
                <FilterItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
            </MasterTableView>
            <EditItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
            <FooterStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
            <FilterItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
               <CommandItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
               <ActiveItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
               <ItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
               <PagerStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" 
                   HorizontalAlign="Left" Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" />
               <SelectedItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
               <FilterMenu Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" 
                 EnableRoundedCorners="True">
               </FilterMenu>
               <HeaderContextMenu Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" 
                   Skin="Simple">
               </HeaderContextMenu>
               </telerik:RadGrid>
```

code behind:

```
public void setSqlDatSource()
    {

        gridSearchL3.DataSource = getsource();

    }


public DataTable getsource()
    {
        string Query;

        Query = @"select distinct h.DocumentNumber 'Document Number' " +
                 " from tblDocumentHeader h    where  h.DocumentHeaderTypeID=3 ";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PinCBusMgtDocs.Properties.Settings.PINCConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con))
        {

            da.Fill(dt);
        }

        return dt;
    }


protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {

      setSqlDatSource();

    }

    protected void gridSearchL3_ColumnCreated1(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Column.UniqueName == "Document Number")
        {
            e.Column.FilterControlWidth = 120;
            e.Column.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(120);
            e.Column.AutoPostBackOnFilter = true;
            e.Column.CurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.Contains;
         }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

ASPX

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="gridSearchL3" runat="server" AllowPagg="True" GridLines="None"
    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="Small"
    PageSize="50" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowSorting="True" ShowStatusBar="True"
    AllowPaging="True" CellSpacing="0" OnColumnCreated="gridSearchL3_ColumnCreated1" EnableLinqExpressions="false">
    <FilterItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="XX-Small" />
    <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="False" />
    <ExportSettings Excel-Format="ExcelML" ExportOnlyData="True" FileName="PinC Group"
        IgnorePaging="True" OpenInNewWindow="True">
        <Excel Format="ExcelML" />
    </ExportSettings>
    <ClientSettings>
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
    </ClientSettings>
    <AlternatingItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    <GroupHeaderItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    <SortingSettings EnableSkinSortStyles="false" />
    <MasterTableView Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small">
        <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to Pdf" />
        <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
        </RowIndicatorColumn>
        <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
        </ExpandCollapseColumn>
        <EditFormSettings>
            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
            </EditColumn>
        </EditFormSettings>
        <ItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" />
        <FilterItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    </MasterTableView>
    <EditItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    <FooterStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    <FilterItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    <CommandItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    <ActiveItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    <ItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    <PagerStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" HorizontalAlign="Left"
        Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" />
    <SelectedItemStyle Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" />
    <FilterMenu Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" EnableRoundedCorners="True">
    </FilterMenu>
    <HeaderContextMenu Font-Names="Eras Medium ITC" Font-Size="X-Small" Skin="Simple">
    </HeaderContextMenu>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

ASPX.CS

```
public void setSqlDatSource()
{

    gridSearchL3.DataSource = getsource();

}


public DataTable getsource()
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Shipper", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ShipperTemp", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("DocumentNumber", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add("CShipper1", "1", "DocumentNumber1");
    dt.Rows.Add("BShipper2", "2", "DocumentNumber2");
    dt.Rows.Add("AShipper3", "3", "DocumentNumber3");
    dt.Rows.Add("EShipper4", "4", "DocumentNumber4");
    dt.Rows.Add("DShipper5", "5", "DocumentNumber5");

    return dt;
}


protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{

    setSqlDatSource();

}

protected void gridSearchL3_ColumnCreated1(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.UniqueName == "DocumentNumber")
    {
        e.Column.FilterControlWidth = 120;
        e.Column.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(120);
        e.Column.AutoPostBackOnFilter = true;
        e.Column.CurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.Contains;
        e.Column.HeaderText = "Document Number";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! i found out later that the column names in sql query should not include spaces or special characters like #,- when binding to the radgrid. i removed them from my sql query and everything works fine now

Comment: @chamara, that was a very nice catch, I hope telerik include this in their supported doc (known issues), if anyone here works at Telerik, can you provide a support doc url where gotchas like this are explained?